# WPF StopStoryboard - after animation stops it does not Bind to the Color property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am new to WPF, I Have a rectangle that I try to animate to flesh red color if some boolean is true. and I want it to stop when the boolean is false. In order to do that, I used the  `<DataTrigger.ExitActions>`
However, I still want my Fill color to change according to the AlertColor, but after the animation is stopped it seems like the binding is stoped also, and the background-color stays LightPink only.
why? how can I fix this and is there a better approach to animate the color only in case of a specific color and stop the animation when the color changes (with Binding)?

The XAML relevant code:

```
 <Rectangle  Width="840" Height="40">
                    <Rectangle.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                            <Setter Property="Fill">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding AlertUnit.AlertColor , FallbackValue=LightPink}"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger   Binding="{Binding AlertUnit.Emergency}"  Value="true" >
                                   <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                      <BeginStoryboard Name="FlashingRedAnimation">
                                          <Storyboard>
                                              <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" To="White" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"
                                                              RepeatBehavior="Forever"></ColorAnimation>
                                          </Storyboard>
                                      </BeginStoryboard>
                                   </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlashingRedAnimation" />
                                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Rectangle.Style>
                </Rectangle>
```

- **edit:**

I found the problem it was a really silly one. the binding should be:

```
  Binding AlertUnit.AlertColor.Color
```

**not:**

```
Binding AlertUnit.AlertColor
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: If the color stays `LightPink`, it indicates that your binding to `AlertUnit.AlertColor` fails. What's the value of this property, how is it defined and how and when do you set it?

Comment: Consider declaring `AlertColor` as Color instead of Brush. You already know that AlertColor is not a terribly great name for a Brush.

Comment: @Clemens what is the benefit/difference of using Color instead of Brush? I continue developing an existing project and in this project all the UI colors that have some logic are Brushes, so I did the same in this new model. (first time working with C# & WPF)

Comment: Then give it at least a sensible name, e.g. `AlertBrush`. Anybody who sees `AlertColor` would think it is a color, including yourself, as this question seems to indicate.

Comment: apart from the name is there any disadvantage of using Brush and not Color?

Answer (score 0):

I produced a similar visual effect by animating the opacitity value of a brush rather than the colour.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type vctrl:perBlinkingBorder}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsBlinking" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="(BlinkingBorderBrush).Opacity">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            AutoReverse="True"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                            From="1"
                            To="0"
                            Duration="0:0:0.5">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

To ensure that the visual effect is removed, I have two brush properties on the [perBlinkingBorder](https://github.com/Peregrine66/PeregrinesView/blob/master/library/Peregrine.WPF.View/Controls/perBlinkingBorder.cs) control, and switch between them when the IsBlinking property is set.

More details and a demo project on my recent [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-animation/).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it was a really silly one.
the binding should be:

```
  Binding AlertUnit.AlertColor.Color
```

not:

```
Binding AlertUnit.AlertColor
```

Thank you all for the help.